# How does one come up with good German names for a submissive girl?

Tags: person-names

I am a sub to a Dom and would like to change my name to celebrate this. What are ways to choose a good German name for this?

Comment: Why don’t you ask your Dom for ideas?

Comment: Cinders, welcome! I just voted to close the question, and rest assured that the context is not the reason. To me, this is just opinion-based (how would you determine whether an answer is “more correct” in comparison?) and would generate a list of options. Please take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more about how the site works and what the rules are, thanks!

Comment: What you can ask us about is *how* to choose such a name or what general linguistic features are fitting such a name. However, even this requires further information from your site such as: To what extent you would like to change your name? Should this be a name that can actually be given to children by (reasonable) parents or can it be nickname material? Are there any practical restrictions? Why are you looking for German names in the first place? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @All: Dass man abhängig vom Geschmack den einen Namen eher mag als  den anderen heißt nicht, dass die Frage opinionbased ist. Wer von seinem eigenen Bias nicht absehen kann soll halt nicht antworten. Wer ein wenig selbstkritisch ist, der kann ja die Bedeutung des eigenen Bias in der Antwort konkret machen. Zwar wüsste ich jetzt keinen deutschen Namen, aber "Dominique" wird für Dominas wegen des gleichen Wortbeginns gerne genommen, für die devote Rolle könnte man Juliette oder Justine aus ... verwenden, wären die nicht französisch.

Comment: @Stephie: Mit Vorschlägen können Begründungen einhergehen, und Begründungen können einleuchtend sein oder nicht. Je einleuchtender das Publikum die Begründung findet, umso eher wird die Antwort hoffentlich hochgewertet - wie bei anderen Antworten zu anderen Fragen auch, bei denen fast immer Geschmacksfragen in die Bewertung mit einfließen.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich bilde mir schon ein, das verstanden zu haben. Und selbst wenn wir hier von keiner Änderung des juristischen bzw. öffentlichen Namens ausgehen (was durchaus gewünscht sein kann, so weit wir wissen), ist ein realistischer Name durchaus kein abwegiges Kriterium. *Dominique, Juliette* und *Justine* sind ja auch Namen, die normal genutzt werden.

Comment: Suchst Du (auch) nach Kosenamen, wie von Janka vorgebracht, oder nach reinen Vornamen, die im Kontext einer solchen Beziehung von Insidern richtig gedeutet werden?

Comment: @userunknown: Ich habe mal *is→can* editiert, in der Hoffnung, dass das weniger missverständlich ist …

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Du kannst nach 2h Kommentare editieren (um nicht zu sagen `fälschen`)? :) Hey, ich will auch Mod werden!

Comment: You should give the names you have been thinking of, and experts here can comment on why they think those names are good or not so good. This would be the proper use of this site.

Comment: If this question is to be reopened, it definitely requires some more context. Before reading the comments, I had no idea what "I am a sub to Dom" is supposed to mean - with *Dom* being capitalized in contrast to *sub*, I had assumed the former to be a name and the latter something like a job.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper  Well, I think it is pretty clear that she speaks about a large and historically important church, no?

Comment: "What" is not a good question in this context because it generates "lists." But "how" is a better question, because we're talking about the process of coming up with a name (e.g. use diminutives) as opposed to the name itself. My reopen vote references the edited question.

Answer (score 3):

German diminutives are formed with *-chen* or *-lein*. Pet names for women are usually names of tiny animals or flowers:

> Katze / Kätzchen
>
> Schaf / Schäfchen
>
> Spatz / Spätzchen
>
> Taube / Täubchen
>
> Hase / Häschen, Häslein
>
> Fuchs / Füchschen, Füchslein
>
> Reh / Rehlein
>
> Rose / Röschen, Röslein
>
> Veilchen
>
> Blume / Blümchen

Though the Umlauts will add an additional heavy metal twist to English speakers, they are clearly "softer" to German ears. And there's also

> Frau / Fräulein

The exact name that you use is less important than the fact that you're "diminishing" it, to serve your sub role.

Comment: Janka, your list is a good example why I VTCed: there are so many options and whether they are a good choice remains purely subjective. And I‘m not even considering that the OP is unclear whether they are looking for (private) pet names or first names that can be used publicly in daily life- Ms Füchslein Smith won’t work too well in this case, would it?

Comment: A sub has to live with that.

Comment: Following your “a sub has to live with that” logic, Vacctajejxydh would also be an option. Just saying.

Comment: Yes, sure, but it wouldn't be German. Plus, the only ones who are punished by using that name are clerks who had to write it down.

Comment: *It has to be embarrassing, not plain stupid.*

Comment: Look, I don‘t think this is going to lead somewhere, but afaik a Dom/Sub relationship is *not* about embarrassing anyone. A good Dom will always have the wellbeing of the Sub on their mind. And the Sub submits to that kind of care, willingly. But the question is closed and hence this discussion moot.

Comment: Ich sehe nicht, dass nach Kosenamen gefragt war. Sowas kann man vorher in Kommentaren abklären.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a "last line" to show that you were demonstrating a principle, as opposed to "making a list."